# Xcode 4 - approved way of switching between views in Storyboards

Tags: xcode, view, storyboard

I have a Storyboarded app and need to switch between views. E.g. when a calculation is complete I want to load up a new view and display the answers...

So what I an trying to do is:

IBAction (Button pressed to calculate answer) {
Do the Maths
Jump to Results View
}

I have read several ways of doing this but none seem to work.
I am trying approaches like:

```
SRViewController *second = [[SRViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SRViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method to complete your required work

for more see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

Comment: will you please accept the answer if you think this is what you need.